# How to authenticate socks5 proxy with puppeteer?

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, puppeteer, socks

I want to use puppeteer and socks5 proxy with username and password. Is there a way to make it working?

Non-working solutions:

#1
'proxy-chain' package only supports `http`.

#2
`await page.authenticate({username, password});`
also does not provide socks5 per-page auth. It only does http(s)